# Issue while installing Realignment for JD-Eclipse

Tags: java, decompiling, jd-eclipse

I'm trying to debug a .class file using JD-Eclipse plugin. But while debugging some of the decompiled lines are skipping even after placing the break points in desired lines. After googling i came to know about another plugin called "realignment.jd.ide.eclipse_1.0.2.jar". 
I performed the install procedure as per the SourceForge page and tried dropping the jar file in eclipse /plugins directory and restarted the eclipse(Also tried the /dropins directory). As per the site If we go under this Preferences/General/Editors/File Associations and select "*.class" file type. There we should choose "Realignment for JD Class File Editor" for Associated editors. But there was nothing as expected.  Please someone guide me in right direction to use this realignment feature.

### Current Environment:

Eclipse IDE    :    Eclipse Kepler

JAVA                   :   JDK 6

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the Realignment plugin. Just install the JD-Ecplise plugin, go to menu Window > Preferences, navigate to Java > Decompiler and check 'Realign line numbers' (you can uncheck 'Show original line numbers' since they will match the decompiled class text)